# Horizintally center menu buttons using css

Tags: html, css, menu, vertical-alignment

Trying to make this vertically centered somehow it does not want to and i see no way even if i wrap labels in another element then i still have problem centering it.

```
div {
    background-color:#00aa00;
}

.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}

.menu li {
    background-color:#aa0000;
    float:left;
}
<ul class="menu">
   <li>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Rock <hr/> News</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2fTj/

Comment: vertical center or horizontal center ?

Comment: I think you should make a clear note.  Your title has `horizontal` and whereas in your question `vertically`, take time to give clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical and Horizontal Center align...

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2fTj/4/)

For Vertical center alignment you should use `display: table-cell;` (in your child element) and `display: table;` (in your parent element).

For Horizontol center alignment you should use `text-align: center;` in your `.menu` and specify the width in `div`.

```
div {
    background-color:#00aa00;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}

.menu li {
    background-color:#aa0000;
    margin-left:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I need home to be vertically aligned with HR of Rock <hr/>News in your example its below it.